# Changing connection strings based on drop down list ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Presently I am creating a dashboard that loads a connection string in Asp.net using VB.

The intent of the program is to show the list of tables in a database and the total number of records in each table. The code below works well with the assignment of only one connection string. The results are shown in a gridview.

```
Public Class Main_Dashboard
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Me.BindGrid()
        End If
    End Sub
 
Private Sub BindGrid()
        Dim constr1 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr1").ConnectionString 'Must put the cpnnection string in the web config file
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr1)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
                                         SELECT @QueryString = COALESCE(@QueryString + ' UNION ALL ','')
                                              + 'SELECT '
                                              + '''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id))
                                              + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + '''' + ' AS [TableName]
                                              , COUNT(*) AS [RowCount] FROM '
                                              + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id))
                                              + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + ' WITH (NOLOCK) '
                                         FROM sys.objects AS sOBJ
                                         WHERE
                                              sOBJ.type = 'U'
                                              AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
                                         ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id), sOBJ.name ;
                                         EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString;
                                          
 
                                         SELECT
                                              QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName]
                                              , SUM(sdmvPTNS.row_count) AS [RowCount]
                                         FROM
                                              sys.objects AS sOBJ
                                              INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS sdmvPTNS
                                                    ON sOBJ.object_id = sdmvPTNS.object_id
                                         WHERE
                                              sOBJ.type = 'U'
                                              AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
                                              AND sdmvPTNS.index_id < 2
                                         GROUP BY
                                              sOBJ.schema_id
                                              , sOBJ.name
                                         ORDER BY [TableName];")
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        GridView2.DataSource = dt
                        GridView2.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
 
 
Protected Sub OnPageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
        GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        Me.BindGrid()
End Sub
```

**My web config code looks like this:**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="constr1" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName1;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The Catalog is the database name. I want to be able to select the name of a database from a dropdownlist and run the code. For example, if I select DatabaseName1 from the list, it should connect to the connection string assigned to DatabaseName1; if I select DatabaseName2, it should connect to the connection string assigned to DatabaseName2; and so on.

Comment: In code, create a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and load the connection string from the config file into it. Set the `DataSource` property based on your drop-down selection and then get the new connection string from the `ConnectionString` property. If you're always going to set the `DataSource` in code then there's no point including it at all in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to add a connection string, you can go add them to the config file, or let VS (Visual Studio) add the strings to the config file for you.

You can do that from here:

[image]

Well then I would add a standard simple code module to the project
so right click on project exploer add a code module.

So we now have this:

```
Module Module2

    Public Function GetconStr(Optional sDB As String = "") As String

        Dim strCon As String = My.Settings.TEST4

        If sDB <> "" Then
            strCon = strCon.Replace(";Initial Catalog=Test4", ";Initial Catalog=" & sDB)
        End If

        Debug.Print(strCon)


        Return strCon

    End Function

End Module
```

Ok, so now we can get/display all databases. Say like you have.

Lets drop in a drop down box (to select the database).

And drop in a grid view to display the tables.

so, our markup looks like this:

```
        <h2>Select a database</h2>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
          DataTextField="MyDataBases" 
          DataValueField="MyDataBases" Height="26px" Width="203px"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShowTables" 
        runat="server" Text="Show tables" Style="margin-left:25px" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="30%" CssClass="table"></asp:GridView>
```

So now our code is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT name as MyDataBases FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.database_id > 4ORDER BY name",
                        New SqlConnection(GetconStr()))
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            DropDownList1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdShowTables_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdShowTables.Click

    ' put tables to grid for this database

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "select schema_name(t.schema_id) as schema_name,
                t.name as table_name,
                t.modify_date
                from sys.tables t
                order by schema_name,
                table_name;"

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(GetconStr(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

output:

[image]

Comment: The post above was quite helpful. Thank you